# Restrict Access to Site to Site VPN

Tags: vpn

I'm working on setting up an IPSEC site to site VPN, but I only want my development team to have access. How can I restrict access to the site to site VPN. I don't have static IP's in the office, so I can't limit the access by IP. It's a combination of WiFi and hardwired access to the Cisco ASA5606.   I thought of using a RADIUS server, but I'm not sure how to authenticate the clients to use the site to site VPN.

Comment: Would the cut-through-proxy feature work for this?  I found some info about using cut through on the outside coming in for authentication,  couldn't I setup the proxy on the site to site VPN?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you have two options:

1. Create DHCP reservations for the clients that need access to the VPN, then grant access to only those IPs.
2. Create a second client VPN connection that your dev team would need to connect (and authenticate) to before getting access to the site-to-site tunnel.
3. Implement 802.1x authentication on your network and dump dev team clients into a subnet that gets access to the tunnel.

Comment: I was kind of hoping to avoid VPN connections in the office.  It kind of defeats the purpose of having a site to site.   Since I have multiple places handing out IP.  (Wireless and Direct) it might be hard, but maybe I could do that.

Comment: Well, your options are extremely limited. General network connections cannot be easily "authenticated". You either need to authenticate at the PHY layer (802.1x, etc.) or put some sort of internal VPN in place that they can authenticate against.

Comment: The DHCP reservations option is likely your easiest choice, but it's not fool-proof by any stretch security-wise if you have a relatively open network.

Comment: Would a RADIUS server do the trick?  Seems like that's what it's purpose is.  Maybe it only works on Remote/Dialup VPN not for a Site to Site?   I really need some sort of authentication process that does not rely on things that can be easily spoofed.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding things. Your site-to-site tunnel is already up. Radius has nothing to do with that. Additionally, for the site-to-site tunnel to succeed, authentication happens between the two routers, not between the clients on each end. Radius servers definitely are used frequently for this sort of thing, but all they are is an authentication service - you need network-level bits that authenticate your clients against that Radius server. This is where my recommendation of an internal VPN or 802.1x comes in.

Comment: I understand the site to site VPN is independent.  I see examples of authentication when trying to access the internet.    [link](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/56421/asa-cut-through-authentication-proxy-configuration-and-examples)   Seems like if I restrict access to the remote address of the site to site that might work.   Or would the restriction cause the site to site validation to fail because the router can't authenticate with the RADUIS server?

Answer (score 0):

You can try softether VPN Server, and also OpenVpn supports radius auth by pam_radius plugin

Answer (score -1):

This depends on what is hosting the VPN method. For example, some Cisco ASA firewalls have LDAP built in, so you can limit who can use the VPN by setting up Active Directory security groups and specifying that group within the VPN security filtering.

Comment: I'm going to use a ASA 5606.   How would my clients authorize to LDAP?